# How to change element in np.array by index

Tags: python, numpy

How to change an element in np array by index without any loops and if statements.
E.g we have array [1,2,3,4], and every second element, starting from 0, I want to change to 10. So as to get [10,2,10,4].

Comment: `arr[::2] = 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4])
for i in range(len(arr)):
  if i%2==0:
    arr[i]=10
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[10  2 10  4]
```

#### Without Loop and if Statements:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4])
arr[0::2] = 10
```

Output:

```
array([10,  2, 10,  4])
```

I've used Numpy's Slicing which works as `[start:stop:step]`

Comment: Can we do this without any loops and if statements?

Comment: There you go. I've made the edits

Comment: Glad it helped. You can close this question by accepting an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of NumPy slicing:

```
a = np.arange(10)
#array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

a[::2] = 10
#array([10,  1, 10,  3, 10,  5, 10,  7, 10,  9])
```

You can slice an array with the format `[start:stop:step]`. You can read more [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use: `a[::2]=10`